# How to solve first order differential equation by fourier series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I was trying to solve the first order differential equation by fourier series:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\beta x=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x_ne^{int}$$

and $$x'(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty in x_ne^{int}$$

by substituting x(t) and x'(t)  in  above equation. but after that i was stuck.

Where $\beta$  is complex variable. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please show your efforts and where you're stuck to get better response.

Comment: Assume that $x$ has Fourier-coefficients $c_k$. Now how would the Fourier-coefficients of each side of your equation look like (in terms of $c_k$)?

Comment: on the R.H.S i have 1/2. now i have problem how to find the coeffients ?

Comment: You get $(in-β)x_n=\delta_{0,n}\frac12$, which restricts $β$ to specific values if you want a non-constant solution.

Comment: Thanks  LutzL. but how i could achieve its final solution. because someone suggest me that it converts into first kind of bessel function. i am trying my best but totaly stuck with it. if you could help me i shall be very thankfull